# Sequelize with Typescript doesn't resolve type correctly

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

Using sequelize v5:

```
class Organization extends Model<Organization> {
  name!: string
}

Organization.init({...}, {sequelize, ...})
```

Then running the following code:

```
const organizations = await Organization.findAll()
organizations.forEach(o => console.log(o.name))
```

Gives the following error:

```
Parameter 'o' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

This tells me that the `findAll()` return type is not being inferred as `Promise<Organization[]>` as the code in sequelize suggests:

```
public static findAll<M extends Model>(this: { new (): M } & typeof Model, options?: FindOptions): Promise<M[]>;
```

How can I get the `findAll()` call to infer the correct type?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, TypeScript infers the correct type.

See node_modules/sequelize/types/lib/promise.d.ts

```
export const Promise: typeof Bluebird;
```

typeof Bluebird is any, so Promise is any.

So sad.